# Executing wrong query by sequlize ORM

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
  blogs.findAll()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
      res.send(result);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.status(400).send({ msg: 'blogs not found' });
    });
```

This code executing (default):

```
SELECT `user_id`, `id`, `title`, `description` FROM `blogPosts` AS `blogPost`;
```

And in database there is only **blogPost** table not **blogPosts**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default sequelize will create tableName in plural format. If you want to change that you can do that by using `freezeTableName: true` option.